# Start Animation when Scrolling to Specific Element Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please Guys , I Tried To Make An Animation Without Plugin Or Something , But I Tried Many times but I couldn't do it ,

That's My code , If anyone Can Solve It .

I want The animation Start Only when The User Scroll down To The Animation Place .
https://codepen.io/abcari/pen/pdyPjy

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(".skill-level").is(".htcss:visible")) {

        $(".htcss").animate({ width: $(".htcss").data('width') + "%" }, 
2500);

    }
});
```

Comment: i see, your animation started only when i scrolled to that part. : ) which browser you are using?

Comment: i Use Google Chrome Yeah but sometimes I Don't know it Start Before I Scroll to it .

Answer (score 1):

A simpler example would be this:

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - 100 >= $(".target").offset().top){
    alert("On viewport");
  }
})
```

```css
body{
  padding-top: 150vh;
}

.target{
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="target">
</div>
```

Comment: Really Thanks you Very Much Man For Your Help , That Helps me A Lot , Man Can i Ask U if i want it to Start the Time when it appears on the screen .

Comment: In that case you add the window height. Check the snippet, I've updated it.

Comment: yeah i saw it But My Question meant for Example Just When it's visible after 50px Or Something like that .

Comment: I've added "-100" substraction, you decide how much you want yourself. Updated again.

Comment: @Patrek no problem. Make sure to upvote and mark as solved, if it solved your problem.

Comment: yeah Bro I Tried Form The First But I Can't Do it Because Of reputation .